# python class call function without indicate function name

Tags: python, class, pytorch

I was learning pytorch and I encountered a case I could not understand what's happening. Here is a class called MLP, with init function and a forward function. When I pass `X` as a parameter to the `MLP` instance `net`, without using `net.forward(X)`, it seems `forward` function has been autimatically called. Why this is the case?

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.nn import functional as F 

class MLP(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__() # nn.Module's params
    self.hidden = nn.Linear(20, 256)
    self.out = nn.Linear(256, 10)

  def forward(self, X):
    return self.out(F.relu(self.hidden(X)))
  
X = torch.rand(2, 20)

net = MLP()
net(X)

"""
output of net(X)
tensor([[ 0.0614, -0.0143, -0.0546,  0.1173, -0.1838, -0.1843,  0.0861,  0.1152,
          0.0990,  0.1818],
        [-0.0483, -0.0196,  0.0720,  0.1243,  0.0261, -0.2727, -0.0480,  0.1391,
         -0.0685,  0.2025]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
"""
```

My initial guess is that the forward is the only function is MLP receives a parameter, but after I added another function that takes the same parameters, calling `net(X)` seems still choose `forward` function

```
class MLP(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__() # nn.Module's params
    self.hidden = nn.Linear(20, 256)
    self.out = nn.Linear(256, 10)
  
  def forward2(self, X):
    print("hello")
    return self.out((self.hidden(X)))
  
  def forward(self, X):
    return self.out(F.relu(self.hidden(X)))
  
net = MLP()
net(X)
net.forward(X)
net.forward2(X)
```

then I got

```
>>> net.forward(X)
tensor([[-0.1273, -0.0338, -0.1412, -0.1321, -0.1213,  0.0589,  0.0752,  0.0066,
         -0.0057, -0.1374],
        [-0.1660, -0.0044, -0.1765, -0.0451, -0.0386,  0.0824,  0.0486, -0.1293,
          0.0511, -0.1285]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
>>> net.forward2(X)
hello
tensor([[-0.2027, -0.2304, -0.3597, -0.3741, -0.5000, -0.2698,  0.2464,  0.1709,
         -0.2262, -0.1462],
        [-0.1168, -0.0417, -0.3584, -0.3133, -0.2366, -0.1521,  0.2428,  0.0043,
         -0.1296, -0.2021]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
>>> net(X)
tensor([[-0.1273, -0.0338, -0.1412, -0.1321, -0.1213,  0.0589,  0.0752,  0.0066,
         -0.0057, -0.1374],
        [-0.1660, -0.0044, -0.1765, -0.0451, -0.0386,  0.0824,  0.0486, -0.1293,
          0.0511, -0.1285]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
```

What did I miss? Really appreciate with any help!

Comment: Your subclass  instance has a `__call__()` function that calls `forward` within it. In fact you shouldn't call `forward` manually because the hooks are called from within `__call__()`. You define forward so you can tell it the the computation performed at every call of the subclass instance.

Comment: Thank you very much, with `print(inspect.getsource(net.__call__))` I saw where it calls the `forward` function.